# Cannot implement tester program for class

Tags: java

This is a homework assignment and is also my first Java program.  I wrote a StudentAverage class, now I want to test the class methods, but when I write my tester program, the IDE is telling me that I cannot declare my main static. I am using Eclipse as my IDE.

Since this is a homework assignment and I am still learning Java, I would also appreciate some guidance as to what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 *Program:      StudentAverage, Calculate the student average quizzes taken
 * @author:     Jose Mazorra
 * Date:        July 11, 2013
 * Class:       CIS406
 */

/**
   A student who is taking quizzes.
*/
public class StudentAverage
{ 
    //Instances variables
    private String name;
    private double quizScores;
    private double numOfQuizzesTaken;

   /**
      Constructs a student with a given name.
      @param n the name
   */
   public StudentAverage(String stuName)
   {  
     name = (stuName);
   }

   /**
      Gets the name of this student.
      @return the name
   */
   public String getName()
   {  
     return name;
   }

   /**
      Adds a quiz score.
      @param score the score to add
   */
   public void addQuiz(int score)
   {  
     numOfQuizzesTaken++;
     quizScores = quizScores + score;
   }


   /**
      Gets the sum of all quiz scores.
      @return the total score
   */
   public double getTotalScore()
   {  
     return quizScores;
   }

/**Returns the average of all quiz taken
 * by the student
 * @return average score
 */

public double getAverageScore(){

double avgScore;

avgScore = (quizScores / numOfQuizzesTaken);

return avgScore;

}

public class StudentAverageTester{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        StudentAverage student = new StudentAverage()

        student.name("Jose");
        student.numOfQuizzesTaken(10);
        student.quizScores(400);

        double avg = student.avgScore();

        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(avg);
        System.out.println("Expected 40");



    }


}

}
```

Comment: Are both `public` classes in the same file?

Comment: Either remove the `public` keyword in the second class or move it to its own seperate file

Comment: Consider reading up on jUnit and using that to test your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating one class another class.I don't think you intend to do that.Also if both these classes are in one file only one class can be public.Better move each class to its separate file

**Update:**

> So the Issue here is that you are creating Inner class and in Java
>   inner classes cannot have static methods.Because an inner class is
>   implicitly associated with an instance of its outer class, it cannot
>   define any static methods itself. Since a static nested class cannot
>   refer directly to instance variables or methods defined in its
>   enclosing class, it can use them only through an object reference,
>   it's safe to declare static methods in a static nested class.

Comment: *You are creating one class another class* I would suggest to rethink what you're going to write, this sentence doesn't have too much sense. And you can have several classes in a single java file, but just one of them can be `public` top `class` (if that's what you were trying to say).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I said one class another class to simply nested class  terminology.Considering the fact that asker is writing his first java code you won't expect him to write nested class.And regarding one public class per file this is what I actually said in my answer.

Comment: When I started my Java learning I created inner classes without knowing their real impact on the application design, for me making it work was enough :). Of course, now I know it's not like that and I would prefer that this idea is pretty clear for OP. Besides, OP says that * IDE is telling me that I cannot declare my main static* (which is really odd, by the way) instead of *The public type <ClassName> must be defined in its own file* that will be the error by having 2 `public` classes in the same file.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You are right. static method in non-static nested class leads to _The method main cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type_ in eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You have created `StudentAverageTester` as a non-static inner class of `StudentAverage`. Non-static inner classes are not permitted to have `static` declarations, that is why you are seeing the compilation error (see [JLS 8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)).

It would really be better if you extracted the `StudentAverageTester` class into it's own `StudentAverageTester.java` file.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few mistakes in your code. First thing, do what everyone sais and put `StudentAverageTester` in its own file. Currently, you are declaring inside the `StudentAverage` class. You also did not declare a no arg constructor in your `StudentAverage` class. In `StudentAverageTester` you have

```
StudentAverage student = new StudentAverage()
```

but it should be

```
StudentAverage student = new StudentAverage("Some name")
```

You also forgot the semi colon.

**UPDATE**

Your `name` property is private. You can't access it like that in `StudentAverageTester`. You need to declare a setter method as in `setName(String name)`.

Consider reviewing your `StudentAverageTester` class. You are calling methods you did not define and accessing private members directly. You can't do that. Use setters and getters.

Comment: In fact, if you add `static` marker to `StudentAverageTester` you will see the other compiler error messages and after fixing them the program will compile and run as expected.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Oh yeah, there's a lot of mistakes. I'll fix it for him. I've been there.

Comment: IMO fixing OP's errors is part of his homework, so it would be better to just help him to solve the problem stated in question instead of solving his/her assignment. The main problem is having a `static` method in an inner class (as Jonathan's answer points).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yep, you're right. Learning pains are always a good thing.

Comment: These are more like labor pains, or in my case kidney stone pains. :-)

Comment: @user2559274 lol, it's ALWAYS hard at the beginning. We've all been there. Always practice diligently and don't give up. Feel free to ask me anything if you are still stuck.

Comment: Thank you, after reading all of the comments and after some major pains, I was able to get my program to work.

Comment: @user2559274 Good to hear. Good luck with everything :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments and suggestions. It was really helpful. I followed the suggestions and created 2 files. One for my tester and one for the main class.

Here is my tester class code

```
class StudentTester {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        StudentAverage testAverage = new StudentAverage("Jose Mazorra", 50);

            testAverage.addQuiz(900);
            String name = testAverage.getName();

            double avg = testAverage.getAverageScore();

            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(avg);


    }

}
```

It was much easiear to create separate files than doing what I was originally doing which was to have everything in one file. Much cleaner and easier to maintan.
I also made some modifications to my main clase code:

```
    /**
   A student who is taking quizzes.
*/
public class StudentAverage
{ 
    //Instances variables
    private String name;
    private double quizScores;
    private double numOfQuizzesTaken;

    /**
     * Constructs a Student object with a name "Jose Mazorra" and zero total quiz score
     */
    public StudentAverage()
    {
        name = "Jose mazorra";
        quizScores = 0;
        numOfQuizzesTaken = 1;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a Student object with an initial name and total quiz score
     */
    public StudentAverage(String pName, double pQuizScore)
    {
        name = pName;
        quizScores = pQuizScore;
        numOfQuizzesTaken = 20;
    }


   /**
      Gets the name of this student.
      @return the name
   */
   public String getName()
   {  
     return name;
   }

   /**
      Adds a quiz score.
      @param score the score to add
   */
   public void addQuiz(int score)
   {  
       quizScores = quizScores + score;
   }


  /**
      Gets the sum of all quiz scores.
      @return the total score
   */
   public double getTotalScore()
   {  
     return quizScores;
   }

/**Returns the average of all quiz taken
 * by the student
 * @return average score
 */

public double getAverageScore(){

double avgScore;

avgScore = (quizScores / numOfQuizzesTaken);

return avgScore;

}

}
```